# Php Preg Match, how can i do this

Tags: php, regex

```
<td class=bilgi_satir width="45%"><b>( PLACE I WANT TO FETCH ) </b></td>

 ( OTHER HTML TAGS )

<td class=bilgi_satir width="25%"><b>( PLACE I WANT TO FETCH ) </b></td>

 ( OTHER HTML TAGS )

<td class=bilgi_satir width="35%"><b>( PLACE I WANT TO FETCH ) </b></td>

 ( OTHER HTML TAGS )
```

How can i fetch them to an array ?

width variable is changing ...

Comment: @nick i'm really noob in php, can you send an example ?

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: Don't use regexes. You'll just end up tearing out hear (yours or coworkers'). Use http://php.net/dom instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to solve an HTML problem with a regular expression, and soon you have two problems.
But if you really want to do this with a dirty regular expression, it can be done. You shouldn't rely on it. The simplest regex is something like:

```
preg_match_all(
    "/<td class=bilgi_satir width=\"..%\"><b>(.*)<\/b>/i",
    $your_html_here, $m
);
```

This returns roughly what you want with `print_r( $m[1] );` (I added 1, 2, 3 to tell 'em apart)

```
Array (
    [0] => ( PLACE I WANT TO FETCH 1 ) 
    [1] => ( PLACE I WANT TO FETCH 2 ) 
    [2] => ( PLACE I WANT TO FETCH 3 ) 
)
```

Best way to do this is with DOM parsing. For example:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML( $your_html_here );
$x = new DOMXPath( $doc );
$results = $x->query("//td[@class='bilgi_satir']//b");

# $results->length now shows 3

$ret = array();
foreach( $results as $count => $result ) {
    printf( "item # %s = %s\n", $count, $result->nodeValue ); # debug only
    $ret[] = $result->nodeValue;
}
```

This will display:

```
item # 0 = ( PLACE I WANT TO FETCH 1) 
item # 1 = ( PLACE I WANT TO FETCH 2) 
item # 2 = ( PLACE I WANT TO FETCH 3)
```

Edit: obviously dumping the node value into an array lets you access via array, as you wanted.

Comment: You my hero. I really LOVED second example. Really thanks ...